# Can an IOS app only support iOS7?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

I built a game which fully optimised with iOS7
many effects are not supported or not run well in iOS6
and cannot run in iOS5.

May I know if it is acceptable by App Store?

and Can I ask user to upgrade to iOS7 if detect device is below iOS7?

thank you

Comment: if you set deployment taget to 7 it will not allow to dwnload user below 6.

Comment: your guys are awesome. very helpful. I will try my best to support iOS6 with less UI-features.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes. You can set but you lose most user my suggestion set iOS6 as your deployment target it's best.

I highly recommend that you only support the latest two versions. Supporting the latest three iOS versions would only be necessary on the brink of a new iOS release. Supporting iOS versions that hardly any of your users have is a waste of time and money. Since Apple users traditionally update their device OS sooner rather than later it is beneficial to follow that trend.

[image]

iPod touch and iPhone 3GS and some of model doesn't have iOS 7.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can alert user if iOS version is less than iOS7 but for that your app needs to support iOS < iOS7 and all features UI and functional should be supported right from minimum supported version. App store may reject your app if it technically supports lower versions but is buggy.

Instead, you should set application deployment target as iOS7. This will allow to download and install your application only on iOS7 and above device.

For setting this goto your Xcode project->Target->Build Settings->iOS Deployment Target and set iOS7.

[image]

So when user visits your app on the app store he will see this for your app.

[image]

Even Apple's own applications like [Pages](https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/pages/id361309726?mt=8), [Keynote](https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/keynote/id361285480?mt=8) support iOS7 and above.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 2):

**Yes**, i know an application that is only supported on iOS 7.0 and above. Check this 
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/buzzfeed/id352969997?mt=8

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**, your application support only iOS 7. but if you set target version lower like 6 then your application will crash and face negative impact and just showing a popup to user is not a very smart idea for a New application.

Answer (score 1):

yes, you can set your deployment target to iOS7, it will then only install on iOS7 devices. 
NO, you can ask the user to upgrade if your app is not installed in that device, user will by default get a pop-up that this app only support iOS7 and above.

Answer (score 1):

yes, you can set your deployment target to iOS7

you click **Project-> Target-> Build Settings-> iOS Deployment Target and set iOS7**

and also set

you click **Project-> info -> iOS Deployment Target and set iOS7**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Yes** you can do this by set **deployment target to IOS7** which means, your app will run on **IOS7+ devices.** It is `100%` acceptable by app store.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can publish app that only support ios 7

You need to set at two places

[image: In Target Section]

[image: And Project Section]